# Repeatedly change UILabel text with UiButton

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, uibutton, uilabel

I have a few questions that I would like to show with a label. When I press the reset button, the next question in the array does not appear. Should I not place the questions in an array in order for the next element in the array to appear?

```
func theFirstTwoQuestions() {

    // the questions will be contained in an Array
    // change the question label to one of the array values
    // when I press reset the next question will appear

    //self.questionLabel.text? = "\(questionsOneTwo)"
    questionLabel.isHidden = false
    var arrayQuestions = ["What's your name?", "How old are you", "your favorite color is?"]

    for question in arrayQuestions {

        questionLabel.text = arrayQuestions.first
    } 

    resetButton(sender: UIButton)
    arrayQuestions.remove(at: 1)
    questionLabel.text = arrayQuestions.first // "How old are you" is now the first question
}
}
```

Comment: where is button code? you are pressing button and inside you are pressing button again?

Comment: this is just couple lines of something, you are changing label text 4 times and that is all?

Comment: Can you please specify what are you trying to do with your `theFirstTwoQuestions` method

Comment: @arunjos007 Yes. The function "firstTwoQuestions" contains an array of questions. Each element will be shown individually from a label. The resetButton will be pressed and it will change the previous label text.

Comment: okay then Please update your question with proper format and explanation :-)

Comment: @arunjos007 You got it. Thank you, I appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

This should work for your problem.

```
func theFirstTwoQuestions() 
{

// the questions will be contained in an Array
// change the question label to one of the array values
// when I press reset the next question will appear

    questionLabel.isHidden = false
    var arrayQuestions = ["What's your name?", "How old are you", "your favorite color is?"]
    var count = 0


    func onTapResetButton(sender: UIButton)
    {
        self.questionLabel.text = self.arrayQuestions[count] as? String
        if(count < arrayQuestions.count-1)
        {
            count += 1
        }
        else
        {
            count = 0
        }
    }
}
```

[image][image][image]
Let me know if it worked for you. Cheers :]

Comment: unfortunately it didn't work. After the start button was pressed the code questionLabel text did not change to an element within the array.

Comment: Strange coz its working for me. i have added screenshots in my answer..you may check.